# PHP while loop not working

Tags: php, csv

I can't understand why my while loop stops after the first row of data is inserted. Please help. I am trying to upload a .csv file in a MySql table - and if the data already exist, skip and go to the second row.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";
$dbuser = "xxxx";
$dbpass = "xxxx";
mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

fgetcsv_PHP();

function fgetcsv_PHP()
{

    if (($handle = fopen("events.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {

        $length = 1000;
        $delimiter = ",";



        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle) ) !== FALSE )
        {
            // Count number of array elements in $data
            $num = count($data);
            // Print opening table row HTML tag
            $data[5]= strtolower($data[5]);
            $data[11]= "2012-06-22 10:30:40";
            $import="INSERT into candidatedb(event,rec,title,name,surname,email,phone,discip,exper,wheread,comment,stamp) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";


            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from candidatedb WHERE email = '$data[5]' AND surname = '$data[4]'");
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows ($result);
            echo $num_rows;

            if ($num_rows > 0) {

                echo "Email address: $data[5] already exist </br>"; 
            }

            else {      

                    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "Done! $data[5] inserted<br/>";
            }
        }
        // Close the file pointed to by $handle
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

"Done!<br/> $num record uploaded" 
?>




<?php /*?>
       $import="INSERT into candidatedb(event,rec,title,name,surname,email,phone,discip,exper,wheread,comment,stamp) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";

       mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
<?php */?>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: So, what is your problem? What does not work? Are there any errors?

Comment: Another thing to add to @PeeHaa suggestion: don't insert raw values inside a SQL query string, you're exposing yourself to SQL injections. Use mysqli_real_escape_string or (better yet), a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

what ist the output if you try debugging with this:

```
fgetcsv_PHP();

function fgetcsv_PHP() {

$length    = 1000;
$delimiter = ",";
if (($handle = fopen("events.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo "read line: ".implode($data, ';')." <br>\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, the delimiter "," is changed to ";" and all the date is displayed as data;data2;data3; etc..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. It was not the code it was the .csv file. For some reason the .csv version of Excel for Mac "comma separated values" isn't decoded properly by the php function. However if you export the .csv as "windows comma separated (.csv)" then it works like a charm.

[image]

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Maybe Mac csv was a legacy format using CR as line terminator, instead of LF or CR+LF see http://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of